# Group and count in linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, count, group-by

I have a query that needs to retrieve 3 fields:

```
| MaintenanceID | MaintenanceIDCount | StatusID |
|       1       |        2           |    -1    |
|       3       |        2           |    -1    |
```

The field MaintenanceIDCount (like the name says), is the count of MaintenanceID column.

My basic query expression is above:

```
var result = from m in Maintenance
     select new
     {
    m.MaintenanceID,
    m.StatusID
     }
```

The result of this query is:

```
| MaintenanceID | StatusID |
|       1       |    -1    |
|       1       |    -1    |
|       3       |    -1    |
|       3       |    -1    |
```

How can I group and mount my query to retrieve a column with the MaintenanceID column count?

Some tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from m in Maintenance
group m by new { m.MaintenanceID, m.StatusID } into g
select new {
    g.Key.MaintenanceID,
    g.Key.StatusID,
    MaintenanceIDCount = g.Count()
}
```

Comment: Marcin, what's the best way to return it from a method?

Comment: Create a class to store results and update query to return instances of that class instead of anonymous type

Comment: Yeap, is what I made. Thanks.